# How to submit form and load view with results

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How do I submit a form and loads the results from the request in a new view.

I have the following routes

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "GetResults",
        url: "{gueryString}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Result", action = "ShowResults", gueryString = "" }
    );
```

I have a index view with includes a partial view of my form I want to submit.

```
@Html.Partial("../Result/SearchForm")
```

The form itself is

```
@model CodeCompareUk.Models.SearchSubmitModel 

  @using (Html.BeginForm("ShowResults", "Result", method: FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <form role="form">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.searchString, new { @class = "form-control" })
                <a href="javascript:$('form').submit();" class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </form>
    }
```

The new action itself in class ResultController

```
 public ActionResult ShowResults(SearchSubmitModel model)
    {

        RequestExternalComparisonData.ValidateSearchString(model);
        ViewBag.GameComparisonList = RequestExternalComparisonData.DoSearch(model.searchString);
        return View();
    }
```

My Index view

```
<body>

    <div class="section">
        <form>
            @Html.Partial("../Result/SearchForm")
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

The problem is the default index action is always ran on the form submit unless I completely remove the default route, but I need to initially load the index with my form. How do I trigger my new action on the form submit?

Comment: Hard to undertand what your doing here. Why do you have `<a href="javascript...` on the form instead of a standard submit button? If your not hitting the `ShowResults()` method, its probably because your have nested forms (invalid html) - does the main view also have a `<form>` tag? (you need to show the main view also)

Comment: And your routes make no sense at all. You will never reach the `"GetResults"` route because its the same as `"Default"` - i.e. both have a single placeholder

Comment: Thanks for response, I added the form around my partial view(it now shows my queryString in the url). But still does not load my controller.

Comment: Are you using [Post] attribute on your submit controller action?

Comment: What do you mean you _"added the form around my partial view"_ If you have done that its invalid html and will NOT work. Show your main view. And is your  `ShowResults()` decorated with `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: And in your partial you must also remove `<form role="form">`. Again - nested forms are invalid html!

Comment: Your `"Default"` route needs to have `url: "{controller/{action}/{id}",` and you can delete the `"GetResults"` route (no idea what you think that's trying to do). But If you want a specific route then keep it but it must be `url: "Result/ShowResults/{gueryString}",` and you must move it before the default route (the order is important) However it would be easier to just change your GET method to `ShowResults(string id)` instead of `ShowResults(string gueryString)`

Comment: Thanks! Fixing the route URL's worked!